# Implementing data interface in ASP.NET MVC Controller and returning JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have my Controller implement my data interface that returns custom objects. All the objects are serializable and decorated by JSON attributes. So I would like to have my controller method simply be that:

```
  public class MyController : Controller, IMyInterface
  {
        public Foo[] GetFoosByName(string name)
        {
            return new Foo[]{new Foo(name), new Foo(name)}
        }
  }
```

If I do it I get simply "Foo[]" response. What I'd like to get is JSON-serialized Foo objects.
I can easily achieve this by changing my response to be JsonResult:

```
    public JsonResult GetFoosByName(string name)
    {
        return Json(new Foo[]{new Foo(name), new Foo(name)});
    }
```

But then I won't be able to implement IMyInterface in the way that is easily maintainable.

Any ideas on how I can automatically get the behavior as I was returning JsonResult, but still keeping original return types?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would recommend against such a pattern. An MVC Controller should ideally be kind of a top-most layer, and I think it should not implement interfaces. You should implement such interfaces in a service layer, below the MVC Controllers.

However, if you still want to do it so, you can use **explicit implementation** like this.

```
public class MyController : Controller, IMyInterface
{
    public JsonResult GetFoosByName(string name)
    {
        return Json(((IMyInterface)this).GetFoosByName(name));
    } 

    Foo[] IMyInterface.GetFoosByName(string name)
    {
        return new[] { new Foo(name) };
    }    
}
```

Comment: I agree, it is generally not a good pattern to follow, I have a special situation :) Regarding your suggestion, the problem is that if tomorrow IMyInterface has new method added, the person maintaining the code will update the explicit implementation, but may not realize that new JsonResult method should be added.

Comment: You don't have too many options, interface is an interface. I don't have other idea for now.

Comment: Maybe you can introduce an inherited interface like `IMyInterfaceMVC` where you can `new` the methods to return `JsonResult`. When a new method is added, your controller will have error, and when you add the action method, there will be an error with the return type, so you'll be forced to update the `IMyInterfaceMVC` too. You can implement the base interface exlicitly and the `...MVC` interface implicitly. Probably. Haven't tested though, just an idea.